# Draw Grid of circles containg images in them

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, drawable

Currently I am trying to make game in android. I am new to android so I want to learn from you people. Theme of my game is almost like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixelcrater.SmartDots. I have designed a start screen which contains four options, "Single Player","2 Player","Help" and "Exit". When Player click on Single Player or Double a **board should appear containing grid of dots**. Those dots will be alive until Player tap between them to show a line. 
Now the problem is with board. I have defined a 2D Array of circles to show dot(.png) in those circles. **Now I am trying to call image of "black dot" from my res folder in circles.** But I haven't find any help from web which fulfills my requirements. I am mentioning my code below. Please suggest what should I do to show Images in circles. My code executes properly and displays (5*6) grid of circles with black background. Now what I need is to display .png black dot from my res folder in these circles. 
Here is my code file.

```
package com.example.circle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new board(this));
    }
    public class board extends View
    {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        Paint blue=new Paint();
        // Paint green=new Paint();
        int rows=5;
        int cols=6;
        Bitmap [][] dot=new Bitmap[rows][cols];
        Canvas g=new Canvas();
        public board(Context context) {
            super(context);
            p.setARGB(255, 255, 102,0);
            blue.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            // green.setARGB(0, 0, 06, 0);
            for(int y=0; y<cols; y++)
            {
                for(int x=0; x<rows; x++)
                {
                    Bitmap grid= Bitmap.createBitmap(100,100, Config.RGB_565 );

                    dot[x][y]=grid;
                    g.setBitmap(dot[x][y]);
                    g.drawCircle(50, 50, 20, blue);

                }
            }
        }
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawPaint(p);
            for(int y=0; y<cols; y++)
            {
                for(int x=0; x<rows; x++)
                {
                    //g.drawCircle(50, 50, 20, blue);
                    //canvas.drawCircle(50, (x + 1) * 2 * 50, (y + 1) * 2 * 50, blue);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(dot[x][y], x*100, y*100,null);
                }
            } 

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: You have to put your drawing stuff from the constructor into onDraw(). A view draws only in onDraw(), any other drawing operations are wasted. So use canvas.drawCircle in onDraw and get rid of g.drawCircle in your constructor.

Comment: @ElDuderino I changed code according to your instruction. But the problem here is that when I use canvas.drawCircle instead of g.drawCricle in upper for loop it shows "no circle" and when I call canvas.drawCircle in lower for loop it shows only one circel on upper left corner of screen. Please Suggest what should I do?

Comment: I changed location of draw calls from constructor to onDraw method.